# Referencing Ranges in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am trying to reference a range from a different worksheet on another worksheet in the same workbook. I cannot figure out the syntax.

I've tried setting the ranges equal to each other.

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Van Sales").Range("_HebNonEnergy").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("P&L Detail").Range("AI1388").Value`

I am getting an object defined error.

Comment: Are you trying to simply create a formula in one cell that references the other or do you want them to be static values that equal each other but don't reference each other? It's unclear what your goal is here. Can we see the full macro you are writing?

Comment: This code seems to work for me. Double check to make sure the named range  specified matches ("_HebNonEnergy" ) the actual name. Having a typo gives a "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Use the macro recorder. It will write the code for you. You will see how to compose the references.

Comment: Write the formula in a worksheet cell to make sure it functions properly. Then, in the VBE, examine the `.Formula` property of that cell to see how to use it in a VBA routine.